# How to concatenate multiples lines under first occurence of the header?

Tags: regex, unix

I have a file like this:

```
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0746800-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0746800-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0746500-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0746500-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0746500-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0746500-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0746500-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0746500-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0746500-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0746500-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0746500-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0746500-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0746500-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0746500-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0746500-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0746500-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0746500-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0746500-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0746500-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0746500-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0123800-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0123800-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os02t0708500-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os02t0708500-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os02t0708200-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os02t0708200-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os02t0708200-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os02t0708200-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os02t0708200-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os02t0708200-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os02t0707900-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os02t0707900-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os02t0707900-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os02t0707900-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os02t0707900-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os02t0707900-01
scaffold1_size143306
Os02t0707900-03
scaffold2_size121414
Os06t0136900-01
scaffold2_size121414
Os06t0136900-01
scaffold2_size121414
Os06t0136700-01
scaffold2_size121414
Os06t0136600-01
scaffold2_size121414
```

and so on till scaffolds in some 55900. I want my file to have duplicate headers be removed and all the corresponding entries to come within a single header, i.e., I want like this:

```
scaffold1_size143306
Os03t0746800-01
Os03t0746800-01
Os03t0746500-01
Os03t0746500-01
Os03t0746500-01
Os03t0746500-01
Os03t0746500-01
Os03t0746500-01
Os03t0746500-01
Os03t0746500-01
Os03t0746500-01
Os03t0746500-01
Os03t0746500-01
Os03t0746500-01
Os03t0746500-01
Os03t0746500-01
Os03t0746500-01
Os03t0746500-01
Os03t0746500-01
Os03t0746500-01
Os03t0123800-01
Os03t0123800-01
Os02t0708500-01
Os02t0708500-01
Os02t0708200-01
Os02t0708200-01
Os02t0708200-01
Os02t0708200-01
Os02t0708200-01
Os02t0708200-01
Os02t0707900-01
Os02t0707900-01
Os02t0707900-01
Os02t0707900-01
Os02t0707900-01
Os02t0707900-01
Os02t0707900-03
scaffold2_size121414
Os06t0136900-01
Os06t0136900-01
Os06t0136700-01
Os06t0136600-01
Os06t0135900-01
Os06t0135900-01
Os06t0135900-01
Os06t0135900-01
Os06t0135900-01
Os06t0135900-01
Os06t0135900-01
Os06t0135900-01
Os06t0135900-01
Os06t0135900-01
Os06t0134300-01
Os06t0134300-01
Os06t0134300-01
Os06t0134300-01
Os06t0134300-01
Os06t0134300-01
Os06t0134300-01
Os06t0134300-01
```

and so on for each scaffold. The above que has query written in front of it so i am unable to use that expression. how to do this?

Comment: What have you done to try to accomplish this? I presume you're not just looking for someone to write code for you.

Comment: "The above que has query written in front of it..." What above query?

Comment: I have been trying to do it with unix commands like sed so that I can sort out the file but I couldn't get anything by that. after doing the research i got to know that this is possible through regex commands.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391099/how-to-concatenate-multiples-lines-under-first-occurence-of-the-header-using-uni?answertab=votes#tab-top                                                 I have seen in this particular link about the query i ws taking about.

Comment: There is no description of what logic would take you from the first file to the second file. In particular, you are not simply printing the scaffold line only upon first encountering it.  If that were true, then the output file would have the second scaffold followed by exactly four other lines.  But that is not what you have provided as sample output, so I have no idea what you really want here.

Answer (score 0):

A little pseudo-code to get you started:

```
while there are more lines is the file
   Read next line
   if that line starts with "scaffold_size" (header line)
      if it's different than the last "scaffold_size" (or the first read in)
         currentScaffoldSizeLine = the just read in line
         output it
      else
         discard the line, because you don't want duplicate headers
   else
      print the body line
```